# Reduce the size of code - Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My view is somewhat like this:

```
Message : Enable (When I click Enable. Enable will be disables and Disable will be reflected, Same process for all the three)
subscribe : Disable (clickable)
Email : Enable (clickable)
```

My script in View

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var controller = 'settings';
    var base_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';
    var currentuserid = <?php echo $current_user; ?>;
    $( '.mess_disable' ).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            'url' : base_url + '' + controller + '/enablemessagenotification',
            'type' : 'POST',
            'data' : {'currentuserid' : currentuserid },
            'success' : function(data){                                    
                    $('.mess_enable').show();
                    $('.mess_disable').hide();
                    location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
```

My Controller

```
    function enablemessagenotification()
    {
     $userid = $this->input->post('currentuserid');

    $data = array(
                 'email-message'=>'0',
             );

    $this->db->where('id',$userid);
    $this->db->update('users',$data);     
    }
```

The following is working fine.

Here my question is, I'm writing nearly writing 6 function and 6 script (for enable and disable). It's too hard to text for all. It is possible to reduce the code in any way.

Answer (score 2):

If i have understand your code correctly you can do the followings:

-For the script, you can add the same class in every button so you can show or hide them with only one script.

-As for the functions you can add the parameters that you need for your db in an html hidden input which you can pass it in php with the button as showing below:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="email-message" id="mess" value="">
    <button id="mess" class="same-class">Message</button>
```

And with the above info having passed into php you can use one function with a switch most probably in order to serve all the three buttons.